# Looping issue in fetching and display data in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have 24 records in database table. 
I want to display 6 records in each particular list. So, i need 4 list of records basically.

I have tried this way, refer below code snippet for more details.

```
 <?php
        $homeBrands1 =mysql_query("SELECT b.MASTER_ID,b.IMAGES,b.PAGE,b.HOME_LOGO,b.STATUS,m.ID,m.TITLE,m.LOGO FROM cms as b
                      INNER JOIN master as m on m.ID=b.MASTER_ID WHERE b.PAGE='homebrands' AND b.POSITION=1");
        $homeResult1 =mysql_fetch_array($homeBrands1);

        $homeBrands3 =mysql_query("SELECT b.MASTER_ID,b.IMAGES,b.PAGE,b.STATUS,b.HOME_LOGO,m.ID,m.TITLE,m.LOGO FROM cms as b
                      INNER JOIN master as m on m.ID=b.MASTER_ID WHERE b.PAGE='homebrands' AND b.POSITION=3");
        $homeResult3 =mysql_fetch_array($homeBrands3);

        $homeBrands2 =mysql_query("SELECT b.MASTER_ID,b.IMAGES,b.PAGE,b.STATUS,b.HOME_LOGO,m.ID,m.TITLE,m.LOGO FROM cms as b
                      INNER JOIN master as m on m.ID=b.MASTER_ID WHERE b.PAGE='homebrands' AND b.POSITION=2");
        $homeResult2 =mysql_fetch_array($homeBrands2);

        $homeBrands4 =mysql_query("SELECT b.MASTER_ID,b.IMAGES,b.PAGE,b.STATUS,b.HOME_LOGO,m.ID,m.TITLE,m.LOGO FROM cms as b
                      INNER JOIN master as m on m.ID=b.MASTER_ID WHERE b.PAGE='homebrands' AND b.POSITION=4");
        $homeResult4 =mysql_fetch_array($homeBrands4);

        $homeBrands5 =mysql_query("SELECT b.MASTER_ID,b.IMAGES,b.PAGE,b.STATUS,b.HOME_LOGO,m.ID,m.TITLE,m.LOGO FROM cms as b
                      INNER JOIN master as m on m.ID=b.MASTER_ID WHERE b.PAGE='homebrands' AND b.POSITION=5");
        $homeResult5 =mysql_fetch_array($homeBrands5);

        $homeBrands6 =mysql_query("SELECT b.MASTER_ID,b.IMAGES,b.PAGE,b.STATUS,b.HOME_LOGO,m.ID,m.TITLE,m.LOGO FROM cms as b
                      INNER JOIN master as m on m.ID=b.MASTER_ID WHERE b.PAGE='homebrands' AND b.POSITION=6");
        $homeResult6 =mysql_fetch_array($homeBrands6);
     ?>  

      <div class="brands">

        <div class="main-heading">
          <h3>Our<br> Brands</h3>
        </div>
        <ul id="slider1" style="overflow:hidden;">
  <li style="margin-left: -19px !important; margin-right:22px !important;">

    <div class="row" style="padding-left:10px !important; margin-left:1px;">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <div class="brand-cat wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0s">
                <img src="images/brands/<?php echo $homeResult1['IMAGES']; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $homeResult1['TITLE'];?>">
                <div class="brand-name"><img src="images/home_logos/<?php echo $homeResult1['HOME_LOGO'];?>" class="img-responsive" alt=""></div>
                <div class="overlay">
                  <div class="overly-brand-name"><img  src="images/home_logos/<?php echo $homeResult1['HOME_LOGO'];?>" class="img-responsive" alt=""><a href="" onclick="get_details(<?php echo $homeResult1['MASTER_ID'];?>);"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
                  <a href="#" onclick="get_details(<?php echo $homeResult1['MASTER_ID'];?>);" class="viewangale">View more</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="brand-cat wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
                <img src="images/brands/<?php echo $homeResult3['IMAGES']; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $homeResult3['TITLE'];?>">
                <div class="brand-name"><img src="images/home_logos/<?php echo $homeResult3['HOME_LOGO'];?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $homeResult3['TITLE'];?>"></div>
                <div class="overlay">
                  <div class="overly-brand-name"><img src="images/home_logos/<?php echo $homeResult3['HOME_LOGO'];?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $homeResult3['TITLE'];?>"><a href="#" onclick="get_details(<?php echo $homeResult3['MASTER_ID'];?>);"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
                  <a href="#" onclick="get_details(<?php echo $homeResult3['MASTER_ID'];?>);" class="viewangale">View more</a>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <div class="brand-cat stradivarius wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
                <img src="images/brands/<?php echo $homeResult2['IMAGES']; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $homeResult2['TITLE'];?>">
                <div class="brand-name"><img src="images/home_logos/<?php echo $homeResult2['HOME_LOGO'];?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $homeResult2['TITLE'];?>"></div>
                <div class="overlay">
                  <div class="overly-brand-name"><img src="images/home_logos/<?php echo $homeResult2['HOME_LOGO'];?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $homeResult2['TITLE'];?>"><a href="#" onclick="get_details(<?php echo $homeResult2['MASTER_ID'];?>);"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
                  <a href="#" onclick="get_details(<?php echo $homeResult2['MASTER_ID'];?>);" class="viewangale">View more</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="brand-cat wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.5s">
                <img src="images/brands/<?php echo $homeResult4['IMAGES']; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $homeResult4['TITLE'];?>">
                <div class="brand-name"><img src="images/home_logos/<?php echo $homeResult4['HOME_LOGO'];?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $homeResult4['TITLE'];?>"></div>
                <div class="overlay">
                  <div class="overly-brand-name"><img src="images/home_logos/<?php echo $homeResult4['HOME_LOGO'];?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $homeResult4['TITLE'];?>"><a href="#" onclick="get_details(<?php echo $homeResult4['MASTER_ID'];?>);"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>

                <a href="#" onclick="get_details(<?php echo $homeResult4['MASTER_ID'];?>);" class="viewangale">View more</a>
                </div>
              </div>
                </div>
                 <div class="col-sm-6" style="padding-left:10px;">
                  <div class="brand-cat gerry wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
                    <img src="images/brands/<?php echo $homeResult5['IMAGES']; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $homeResult5['TITLE'];?>">
                    <div class="brand-name"><img src="images/home_logos/<?php echo $homeResult5['HOME_LOGO'];?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $homeResult5['TITLE'];?>"></div>
                    <div class="overlay">
                  <div class="overly-brand-name"><img src="images/home_logos/<?php echo $homeResult5['HOME_LOGO'];?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $homeResult5['TITLE'];?>"><a href="#" onclick="get_details(<?php echo $homeResult5['MASTER_ID'];?>);"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
                  <a href="#" onclick="get_details(<?php echo $homeResult5['MASTER_ID'];?>);" class="viewangale">View more</a>
                </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
               <div class="row" style="padding:0px !important;">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <div class="brand-cat wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.5s">
                    <img src="images/brands/<?php echo $homeResult6['IMAGES']; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $homeResult6['TITLE'];?>">
                    <div class="brand-name"><img src="images/home_logos/<?php echo $homeResult6['HOME_LOGO'];?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $homeResult6['TITLE'];?>"></div>
                    <div class="overlay">
                  <div class="overly-brand-name"><img src="images/home_logos/<?php echo $homeResult6['HOME_LOGO'];?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $homeResult6['TITLE'];?>"><a href="" onclick="get_details(<?php echo $homeResult6['MASTER_ID'];?>);"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
                <a href="#" onclick="get_details(<?php echo $homeResult6['MASTER_ID'];?>);" class="viewangale">View more</a>
                </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
             <div style="clear:both"></div>
          </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
  </li>

   <li style="margin-left: -19px !important; margin-right:22px !important;">

  <div class="row" style="padding-left:10px !important; margin-left:1px;">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
              <div class="brand-cat wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0s">
                <img src="images/brands/<?php echo $homeResult1['IMAGES']; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $homeResult1['TITLE'];?>">
                <div class="brand-name"><img src="images/home_logos/<?php echo $homeResult1['HOME_LOGO'];?>" class="img-responsive" alt=""></div>
                <div class="overlay">
                  <div class="overly-brand-name"><img  src="images/home_logos/<?php echo $homeResult1['HOME_LOGO'];?>" class="img-responsive" alt=""><a href="" onclick="get_details(<?php echo $homeResult1['MASTER_ID'];?>);"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
                  <a href="#" onclick="get_details(<?php echo $homeResult1['MASTER_ID'];?>);" class="viewangale">View more</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="brand-cat wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.4s">
                <img src="images/brands/<?php echo $homeResult3['IMAGES']; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $homeResult3['TITLE'];?>">
                <div class="brand-name"><img src="images/home_logos/<?php echo $homeResult3['HOME_LOGO'];?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $homeResult3['TITLE'];?>"></div>
                <div class="overlay">
                  <div class="overly-brand-name"><img src="images/home_logos/<?php echo $homeResult3['HOME_LOGO'];?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $homeResult3['TITLE'];?>"><a href="#" onclick="get_details(<?php echo $homeResult3['MASTER_ID'];?>);"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
                  <a href="#" onclick="get_details(<?php echo $homeResult3['MASTER_ID'];?>);" class="viewangale">View more</a>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-8">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-6">
                  <div class="brand-cat stradivarius wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.3s">
                <img src="images/brands/<?php echo $homeResult2['IMAGES']; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $homeResult2['TITLE'];?>">
                <div class="brand-name"><img src="images/home_logos/<?php echo $homeResult2['HOME_LOGO'];?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $homeResult2['TITLE'];?>"></div>
                <div class="overlay">
                  <div class="overly-brand-name"><img src="images/home_logos/<?php echo $homeResult2['HOME_LOGO'];?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $homeResult2['TITLE'];?>"><a href="#" onclick="get_details(<?php echo $homeResult2['MASTER_ID'];?>);"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
                  <a href="#" onclick="get_details(<?php echo $homeResult2['MASTER_ID'];?>);" class="viewangale">View more</a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="brand-cat wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.5s">
                <img src="images/brands/<?php echo $homeResult4['IMAGES']; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $homeResult4['TITLE'];?>">
                <div class="brand-name"><img src="images/home_logos/<?php echo $homeResult4['HOME_LOGO'];?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $homeResult4['TITLE'];?>"></div>
                <div class="overlay">
                  <div class="overly-brand-name"><img src="images/home_logos/<?php echo $homeResult4['HOME_LOGO'];?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $homeResult4['TITLE'];?>"><a href="#" onclick="get_details(<?php echo $homeResult4['MASTER_ID'];?>);"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>

                <a href="#" onclick="get_details(<?php echo $homeResult4['MASTER_ID'];?>);" class="viewangale">View more</a>
                </div>
              </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-6" style="padding-left:10px;">
                  <div class="brand-cat gerry wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.2s">
                    <img src="images/brands/<?php echo $homeResult5['IMAGES']; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $homeResult5['TITLE'];?>">
                    <div class="brand-name"><img src="images/home_logos/<?php echo $homeResult5['HOME_LOGO'];?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $homeResult5['TITLE'];?>"></div>
                    <div class="overlay">
                  <div class="overly-brand-name"><img src="images/home_logos/<?php echo $homeResult5['HOME_LOGO'];?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $homeResult5['TITLE'];?>"><a href="#" onclick="get_details(<?php echo $homeResult5['MASTER_ID'];?>);"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
                  <a href="#" onclick="get_details(<?php echo $homeResult5['MASTER_ID'];?>);" class="viewangale">View more</a>
                </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
             <div class="row" style="padding:0px !important;">
                <div class="col-sm-12">
                  <div class="brand-cat wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.5s">
                    <img src="images/brands/<?php echo $homeResult6['IMAGES']; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $homeResult6['TITLE'];?>">
                    <div class="brand-name"><img src="images/home_logos/<?php echo $homeResult6['HOME_LOGO'];?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $homeResult6['TITLE'];?>"></div>
                    <div class="overlay">
                  <div class="overly-brand-name"><img src="images/home_logos/<?php echo $homeResult6['HOME_LOGO'];?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $homeResult6['TITLE'];?>"><a href="" onclick="get_details(<?php echo $homeResult6['MASTER_ID'];?>);"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
                <a href="#" onclick="get_details(<?php echo $homeResult6['MASTER_ID'];?>);" class="viewangale">View more</a>
                </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
             <div style="clear:both"></div>
          </div>
       <div style="clear:both"></div>
  </li>

  </ul>

      </div>
```

Can anyone help me on this issue?

Comment: Your source code is very big, and you do not specify exactly what the current problem is. See [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and it would be great if you can provide [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to do one query, and save your results in an array:

```
$homeBrands =mysql_query("SELECT b.MASTER_ID,b.IMAGES,b.PAGE,b.HOME_LOGO,b.STATUS,m.ID,m.TITLE,m.LOGO FROM cms as b
                      INNER JOIN master as m on m.ID=b.MASTER_ID WHERE b.PAGE='homebrands' ORDER BY b.POSITION LIMIT 6");
$homeResult =mysql_fetch_array($homeBrands);
```

Then iterate over the results using a loop (it is the loop that you are missing in your case):

```
<?php
foreach($homeResult as $hr)
{
?>

              <div class="brand-cat wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0s">
                <img src="images/brands/<?php echo $hr['IMAGES']; ?>" class="img-responsive" alt="<?php echo $hr['TITLE'];?>">
                <div class="brand-name"><img src="images/home_logos/<?php echo $hr['HOME_LOGO'];?>" class="img-responsive" alt=""></div>
                <div class="overlay">
                  <div class="overly-brand-name"><img  src="images/home_logos/<?php echo $hr['HOME_LOGO'];?>" class="img-responsive" alt=""><a href="" onclick="get_details(<?php echo $hr['MASTER_ID'];?>);"><i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></div>
                  <a href="#" onclick="get_details(<?php echo $hr['MASTER_ID'];?>);" class="viewangale">View more</a>
                </div>
              </div>

<?php

}

?>
```

And that's all the code you need, regardless of number of results you want to display. Hope you get the idea. The code is not tested